# appropriate way to validate the existence of URI (URL/URN)?

Tags: java, user-interface, networking, thread-safety, uri

here is the deal, I have a `JTextField` with a `KeyListener` so any time I press (release/type) a key, it calls a method (`validateButton()`), which check if the text on the `JTextFile` is a valid URL (in the title says it could be whether a URL or a URN, but, by now, I'm more interested on recognize URL's, but I would appreciate if you consider both of them in your answer) the thing is that every time a press a key, my code tries to establish a connection to the server, so my GUI stops working until the connection is over, so I thought, I'm going to use a thread to the connection, but I would like to "kill/terminate"  the current thread (the one that is checking a URL(if any)) any time a key is press (release/type), to save bandwidth, I know I could do it by pressing a button, (wich will save even more bandwidth) at the end of the edit and if it is valid proceed and if it is not then do something else, but that is not what I'm trying to do; the problem is that is not recommended to kill a thread, but while the thread is establishing the connection I won't be able to call a method or change a property variable to kill him, any idea to do this (using or not the approximation described here).

Thanks in advance

**P.D:** I'm using the next code to check the existance of the url:

```
        URL u = new URL (tfURI.getText());
        HttpURLConnection huc =  ( HttpURLConnection )  u.openConnection (); 
        huc.setRequestMethod ("HEAD");  
        huc.connect () ; 
        code = huc.getResponseCode() ;
```

if the code is different from 404 or any other error code I'm enabling my button otherwise I'm disabling it.

Comment: Maybe you want to only validate the URL after, for example no Input was made for 5 or 10 seconds.This is actually no solution but maybe a workaround? Also you could reduce the Load of your Http connections by Using ThreadPools: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html . You will have methods like shutdownNow(), to reduce the number of running Threads: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow()